# firing dojo onchange based on value selected in combobox

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

When calling `dojo.wipein` and `dojo.wipeout` from buttons, everything works great. **But** calling them based on the value in a combobox: I can't do it. Does anyone know how to make calling **client** side script depend on the value of a combobox?

In other words, if I change the combobox to "Yes", fire `dojo.wipein`, if I change the combobox to "No", fire `dojo.wipeout`.

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your help. Here is the code that worked. I am a beginner in javascript, which might show, but it works.

```
var comboValue = dojo.byId("#{id:comboBox1}").value
if (comboValue == 'Yes'){
dojo.fx.wipeOut({node:'Lewiston',duration:400}).play();
}else if (comboValue == 'No'){
dojo.fx.wipeIn({node:'Lewiston',duration:400}).play();
}else{
alert("the value is neither yes nor no!")
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `onChange` event of combo box?

Comment: Yes. I can get the code to run onchange but don't know how to make it call or not call dojo code based on the value in the combobox.

Comment: Nate. I'm not sure how to help you further unless you expand your question. If you have a button that you're calling your dojo code in, then you should be able to get the value in CSJS through the code I posted below. If you can give me the structure of your combo box in XPages, I could refine it, but there shouldn't be much to it. Is your end goal to have the code in the buttons or to fire automatically?

Comment: Hi Aaron- thank you very much for your response here, and below. I'm very s l o w, but I am going to work on it more this morning (using the help provided below). I will definitely post my code if it's still not working after this run at it. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Client Side JavaScript, use the following function:

```
dojo.byId("#{id:FieldID}").value
```

Where Field ID is the ID property of your XSP object. This will calculate out the full rendered ID of the element and return its value to use in your client script.

Comment: Aaron-Thank you. You were correct in that the key to my issue (I think) was that I was pointing to the literal names of the elements in my xPage. Using the code you provided above to get the value of my comboBox worked! I also want to thank the other contributors, which helped as well, but I accepted this answer because it was the key, I think. I posted my code in my post above because it looks so bad down here.

Comment: Awesome, Nate. I'm glad this worked for you. And we all start out somewhere, that's what this community is here for!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   onKeyUp: function(evt){
        if (this.value == 'Yes'){
            //dojo.wipein       
        }else if this.value == 'No'){
            //dojo.wpieout
        }else{
            //others
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dojo.connect(myComboBox, 'onChange', function (evt) {
    var value = myComboBox.get("value");
    if(value == "1")
         // do one thing
    else
         // do the other thing
});
```